# Sensorfusion of odometry, accelerometer and gyroscope using Indirect Kalman Filter

Tags: localization, kalman-filter, wheeled-robot, sensor-fusion

I'm trying to implement an indirect Kalman for pose estimation of a wheeled robot.
I found two papers that describe this approach.

- [CMU. Journal (2006) Vol. 5(1)](http://www.thaiscience.info/journals/Article/CMUJ/10325060.pdf)
- [IFAC Conference on Embedded Systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667015404410)

For this post I will reference the second paper, since it is much more detailed.

### My understanding of this approach

In order to estimate the vehicle pose *(xy-coords and orientation)*, two sources of information are fused together. Both odometry and accelerometer combined with gyroscope provide the relative position and rotation information *(xy-velocities and rotational speed)* and that can be integrated to get the pose.

Since both methods are error-prone their outputs are compared and used to estimate those errors using a Kalman filter **[red arrow]**. This estimation is fed back to the sensor models that were compared as input **[light blue arrows]**.

[image: Multi-Sensor Data Fusion Block Diagram]
In the second paper I mentioned almost all components needed for implementation are described in detail:

> The final measurement and observation model equations used for data
>   fusion in state space model form are as follows:
>
> ```
> ΔX(t + 1) = A(t) ∙ ΔX(t) + w(t)
> ΔY(t) = C(t, VL, VR, ωe, Ax, Ay, Ω) ∙ ΔX(t) + v(t)
> ```
>
> Where
>
> ```
> A(t) = [A1 A2 A3]
> C(t, VL, VR, ωe, Ax, Ay, Ω) = [C1 C2 C3]
> Ax(t), Ay(t) = Accelerometer Readings
> Ω(t) = Gyroscope Readings
> VL(t), VR(t) = Linear Velocity from Encoders
> ωe(t) = Angular Velocity from Encoders
> ΔT = Samping Time
> ```

Using naming conventions from above I would asume the following Filter structure:

[image: Kalman filter structure]

*C(t) = C(t, VL, VR, ωe, Ax, Ay, Ω)*

My problem is that all papers and descriptions I found so far didn't really explain how ΔY is used. I know how Kalman filters work in general but I have no idea how ΔY can update ΔX (I've marked this part with questionmarks in the picture above). Do you know how the Measurement Update could work here?